# Replace one or more elements in a nested list

Tags: list, replace, prolog

I am trying to achieve this:

Given `OldList`, replace any item if the item fulfills a goal `(oldNew)`; if not, do not replace the item.

Return a `NewList` with replaced items that has the same structure (i.e. same nesting) as `OldList`.

I get it to work (see my code) for the special case `OldList = [a, b, c]` but I would like to write a predicate that generalizes across list lengths and nested lists, e.g. also for `OldList = [a, [b, c, [d, e]]]`.

Thanks in advance!
/JC

```
oldNew(fruit, banana).
oldNew(car, ferrari).

replace(OldList, NewList):-
    [X1, X2, X3] = OldList,
    (oldNew(X1, Y1); Y1 = X1),
    (oldNew(X2, Y2); Y2 = X2),
    (oldNew(X3, Y3); Y3 = X3),
    (oldNew(X1, Y1); oldNew(X2, Y2), oldNew(X3, Y3)),
    NewList = [Y1, Y2, Y3].
```

EDIT1:

Got it to work with arbitrary list lengths; but i still don't know how to handle nested lists.

```
replace2(OldList, NewList):-
    [H | T] = OldList,
    oldNew(H, NewHead),
    NewList = [NewHead | T].
replace2(OldList, NewList):-
    [H | T] = OldList,
    replace2(T, NewTail),
    NewList = [H | NewTail].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the pattern matching is made explicit in the head. The code is clearer:

```
replace2([], []).
replace2([H|T], [Ht|Tt]) :-
  (  oldNew(H, Ht)
  -> true
  ;  is_list(H)
  -> replace2(H, Ht)
  ;  H = Ht
  ),
  replace2(T, Tt).
```

In SWI-Prolog libraries [apply](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=apply) and [yall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=yall) allow for slightly shorter code:

```
replace2(L, T) :- maplist([H,Ht]>>
  (  oldNew(H, Ht)
  -> true
  ;  is_list(H)
  -> replace2(H, Ht)
  ;  H = Ht
  ), L, T).
```

You can see the bracketed disjunction has been copy and pasted from the former definition. It's a lambda application...

```
?- replace2([aa, car, apple, fruit, any, [aa, car, apple, banana, any]], T).
T = [aa, ferrari, apple, banana, any, [aa, ferrari, apple|...]].
```

Comment: Nice use of `apply` and `yall`.